# Can I save a record in a Windows Gadget in a file or other storage (database, etc.)?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-desktop-gadgets

I'm planning to create a simple gadget to create a TO DO list application. **This is just for practice and to explore Windows Gadget**. How can I store the values in the database? As much as possible, I don't want to set up a local http handler file to be a means to store value to file or database.

**Note**: I tag this with html and javascript since I'm aware it uses such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once installed, gadgets run with all the permissions of the logged in user. So you should be able to access the local file system and instantiate COM objects such as ADO to connect to a database.

The chap here wrote a gadget settings persistence manager to allow gadgets to save their settings between being uninstalled and re-installed in the sidebar. He uses the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` to write out settings to a file:

> http://channel9.msdn.com/playground/Sandbox/231595/

This is also worthwhile reading to understand gadget security:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965881(VS.85).aspx